# get class from a proxy object

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following code. When I call remove, I pass in a proxy that I get from entityManager.getReference. But entity.getClass() fails. How do i get the class information of a proxy

```
 public <T extends BaseEntity> void remove(T entity) throws RemoveException {
    //get the actual object
    entity = (T)getEntityManager().find(entity.getClass(), entity.getId());
    //delete the object
    getEntityManager().remove(entity);

}

Unknown entity: com.merc.domain.EventLog_$$_javassist_3; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.merc.domain.EventLog_$$_javassist_3
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: com.merc.domain.EventLog_$$_javassist_3; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.merc.domain.EventLog_$$_javassist_3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong ... but actually you put your entity into the function, just to get its class and id to find it again and then delete it? I would guess just drop the line:

```
entity = (T)getEntityManager().find(entity.getClass(), entity.getId());
```

and it should work.

Comment: The reason I am doing that is, if the object is not in persistant context than load it in context and then remove. Not sure how to avoid that

Comment: This raises the question how you get to the object if it is not in context?

Comment: You are fighting the framework ... do not try to fix the "remove" method but find and fix the cause of your problem.

Comment: i fixed the remove as you suggested and put a transaction around the service method that calls remove